# Accessing ViewContext in Razor Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a helper method like this:

```
@helper Message(Func<object, object> markup) {
    <tr class="message">
        <td width="100%" style="padding-bottom: 1em; color: #333333; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.3">
            @markup.DynamicInvoke(this.ViewContext)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

that I call with razor markup, for example:

```
@<text>
    We are writing to let you know that @ViewBag.HostName has canceled @ViewBag.TripName and we've removed the trip from your My Trips page.
    <br />
    <br />
    To plan a new trip, go back to Travefy
    <br />
</text>
```

However, I don't know the syntax to get the page's `ViewContext`, because while in an example I saw `this.ViewContext`, `this` does not exist in the helper. Any ideas where I can access it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ViewContext object to your helper method as a parameter.